# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2 - why is that?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a list of items and for some purpose, I have divided that list into two more ArrayList based on some criteria. When I have added all items of the combined list into 2 separate lists then I am not getting any error but If I add some items of the combined list into 1 and some items into 2 then I am getting an error. Tell me how to resolve "IndexOuOfBoundError."

Code: Adding data from combined list to 2 lists

```
            if (modelRipeExpiryArrayList.size() > 0) {


        for (int i = 0; i < modelRipeExpiryArrayList.size(); i++) {


            if (!(modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getExpiryDate().equals("")) && modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getIsRipe() == 1) {


                explist.add(modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getItemName() + "@" + modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getExpiryDate());

                ripeList.add(modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getItemName());

            } else if ((modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getExpiryDate().equals("")) && modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getIsRipe() == 1) {

                ripeList.add(modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getItemName());

            } else if (!(modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getExpiryDate().equals("")) && modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getIsRipe() == 0) {


                explist.add(modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getItemName() + "@" + modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(i).getExpiryDate());

            }


        }

        Log.e("TAG", "getInitialized: "+ripeList.size() +"((" +explist.size() );



        AdapterExpHome adapterExpHome = new AdapterExpHome(getActivity(), modelRipeExpiryArrayList,  explist, HomeFragment.this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager elayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        exp_list.setLayoutManager(elayoutManager);
        exp_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        exp_list.setAdapter(adapterExpHome);
        adapterExpHome.notifyDataSetChanged();


        AdapterHomeRipe adapterHomeRipe = new AdapterHomeRipe(getActivity(), modelRipeExpiryArrayList,  ripeList, HomeFragment.this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        ripe_list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ripe_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        ripe_list.setAdapter(adapterHomeRipe);
        adapterHomeRipe.notifyDataSetChanged();




    }
```

Code for Adapter :

```
       public class AdapterExpHome extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterExpHome.MyViewHolder> {


Context context;
FragmentRipe fragmentRipe;
ArrayList<ModelRipeExpiry> modelRipeExpiryArrayList;

ArrayList<String> explist;
ArrayList<String> ripeList;

int qty;


public AdapterExpHome(Context context,ArrayList<ModelRipeExpiry> modelRipeExpiryArrayList,  ArrayList<String> explist,  HomeFragment homeFragment) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelRipeExpiryArrayList = modelRipeExpiryArrayList;
    this.explist = explist;

    this.fragmentRipe = fragmentRipe;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_exp_home, parent, false);


    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        String expVeggie[] = explist.get(position).split("@");
        String veggieName = expVeggie[0];
        String expDate = expVeggie[1];

        holder.txtVeggie.setText(veggieName);



    if (position % 2 == 0) {

        holder.layExp.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGrey));


    } else {

        holder.layExp.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));



    }







}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return explist.size() ;
}

private static class ViewHolder {


}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtVeggie, txtExpiryDay;
    RelativeLayout layExp;
    LinearLayout layMain;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        txtExpiryDay = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtExpiryDay);
        txtVeggie = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expVeggie1);
        layExp = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layExp);


        layMain = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layMain) ;



    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Comment: @pappbence96 holder.txtRipeVeggie.setText(ripeList.get(position));

Comment: comment out this line `Log.e("TAG", "adapterRipe: "+ ripeList.get(position));` The reason is your adapter size `modelRipeExpiryArrayList` and `ripeList` are not the same in size.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma still not working. Throwing error on next line

Comment: Throwing error on next line ??? logs  please

Comment: @KrishnaSharma . Throwing error on  String expVeggie[] = explist.get(position).split("@");

Comment: Thats what the issue is, your adapter size if different than `explist.size`. It should had to `modelRipeExpiry.get(position)`

Comment: You split your longer list into 2 shorter lists. Then you passed your long list into the adapter and in the adapter you are accessing the shorter lists. Of course you're getting IOOB exceptions.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma have removed modelRipeExpiry.get(position)  but still getting error

Comment: You just need to keep the adapter size and list both in sync

Comment: @KrishnaSharma check my edited adapter code now

Comment: Looks good now, but now you must be getting some other exception. try to split only if item contains @ `String expVeggie[] = explist.get(position).split("@");
   if(expVeggie!=null && expVeggie.length>1){
     String veggieName = expVeggie[0];
     String expDate = expVeggie[1];
     holder.txtVeggie.setText(veggieName);
   }
        
`

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical issue in your code. Though the loop section and dividing data to two different list is fine. I have noticed following things based on your code snippet:

There is redundant code after divide of main list in two different lists. check my comment:

```
exp_list.setAdapter(adapterExpHome);
adapterExpHome.notifyDataSetChanged(); //DON'T CALL THIS LINE AS MEANINGLESS JUST AFTER setAdapter()
.
.
.
ripe_list.setAdapter(adapterHomeRipe);
adapterHomeRipe.notifyDataSetChanged(); //DON'T CALL THIS LINE AS MEANINGLESS JUST AFTER setAdapter()
```

Now the logical error which is basically in **Adapter section**. In adapter you are passing two array one is main as modelRipeExpiryArrayList having all data and other ripeList which can have less that. Now suppose main list has 10 items and ripeList has 6 item. So you need to create your adapter based on ripseList instead of modelRipeExpiryArrayList.

What you are doing is that you are creating item based on modelRipeExpiryArrayList and fetching data from ripeList. As it has 6 items (based on above example) so if you call `ripeList.get(8)` then it will throw "IndexOuOfBoundException" as eighth index item is available in `modelRipeExpiryArrayList` but not in `ripeList`.

Solution:

change the code in adapter from -

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelRipeExpiryArrayList.size();
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ripeList.size();
}
```

Now further, change the code from -

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    modelRipeExpiry = modelRipeExpiryArrayList.get(position); //Don't create model as a class variable

    Log.e("TAG", "adapterRipe: "+ ripeList.get(position));
```

to

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String ripeItem = ripeList.get(position);

    Log.e("TAG", "adapterRipe: "+ ripeList.get(position));
```

Create a different Adapter for explist.